# Recargar form hijo dentro de Panel

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Antes que nada, quisiera pedir disculpas por mi manera de formular preguntas, pues soy completamente novato en esto, así que estoy abierto a responder dudas y encontrar una solución.

Tengo un form hijo abierto dentro de un objeto Panel del form padre así:

```
    public Form activeForm;
        public void AbrirForm(Form childForm)
        {
            if (activeForm != null) activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panelDesktop.Controls.Add(childForm);
            panelDesktop.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
            lblTitulo.Text = childForm.Text;
        }
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClientes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clientes clientes = new Clientes();
            AbrirForm(clientes);
        }
```

Lo que deseo hacer es recargar el formulario Clientes de una forma "limpia", es decir, vaciar todos los DataGridViews y TextBoxes, pero evitando el uso de varios `Clear()`.
En pocas palabras, programar un botón "Nuevo Clientes" que me permita abrir un nuevo form `Clientes` dentro del form padre `Menú`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! "Lo que deseo hacer es recargar el formulario Clientes de una forma "limpia"." <- que quiere decir esto?

Comment: A que te refieres con recargar?

Comment: @Yussef, ya hice una edición de mi consulta, agradecería que la volvieras a ver :)

Comment: Pero ese código no te abre cada vez un form limpio????

Comment: @Yussef lo hace, pero como puedo volver a hacer lo mismo desde un botón en el form Clientes ya abierto?

Comment: En el constructor de Clientes pones que acepte como parámetro el padre, luego lo instancias new Clientes(this), y desde el form hijo ya tienes acceso al padre. Luego llamas padre.AbrirForm(new Clientes(padre)). Si pones el código de Clientes y del padre te puedo dar una respuesta con el código completo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez necesites esto:

```
this.Controls.Clear(); 
InitializeComponent();
```

Dentro de tu form Clientes